# AVA: setup different timeout for each test case

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, ecmascript-6, ava

I writing asynchronous tests using AVA, and need to setup custom timeout for each test cases. I've not found out any information about this possibility and my tests seems like this:

```js
import test from 'ava';

test.cb('super test', t => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        t.is(1, 1);
        t.end();
    }, 10000);

    setTimeout(() => {
        t.fail("Timeout error!");
        t.end();
    }, 100);
});
```

Does anybody know another way to implement this in AVA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if AVA has something like this built in. I suspect not, as it seems like quite an unusual use-case.

But you could create a utility function that implements some kind of a "timeout test":

```
import test from 'ava';

function timeout (ms, fn) {
   return function (t) {
       setTimeout(() => {
           t.fail("Timeout error!")
           t.end()
       }, ms)
       fn(t)
   }
}

test.cb('super test', timeout(10000, t => {
    t.is(1, 1);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I liked your approach to solving the problem and now I use it in my project - it allowed me to reduce the number of code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

There's an open issue to support this in AVA itself: https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1565

Until that lands you'll have to manage a timer yourself. Don't forget to clear it once your normal test completes.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this issue before, but I was hoping that someone knows how to do this, knows any workaround or/and extension points how we can add this custom functionality.

Comment: @MaxVinogradov, there are workarounds with sample code in the linked issue.